# Saving TensorFlow model (ensemble) to one pickle file, instead of multiple pickles, in Python

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, pickle

I am looking to deploy a 50 model ensemble for a regression problem, with each model being a Keras.Sequential Neural Network.

Below is a (simplified to 3 models) version of my code, that runs and works fine.

However, I don't want to create a pickle file for every individual model, and so is there a way of creating a class with a list of all the models, resulting in me having to save/load only one pickle file?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = pd.read_csv("Training Data.csv").fillna(0)
X_train = train.drop(['ID_NUMBER','DATE','X','Y','Z'],axis=1)
Y_train = train[['X','Y','Z']]

EPOCHS = 1500
BATCH_SIZE = 256

#Defining the 3 layered Neural Network
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.softplus,
                       input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(500, activation=tf.nn.softplus),
    keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])

    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
    return model

model0 = build_model()
# Store training stats
history0 = model0.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_split=0.0, verbose=1)

model1 = build_model()
# Store training stats
history1 = model1.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_split=0.0, verbose=1)

model2 = build_model()
# Store training stats
history2 = model2.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_split=0.0, verbose=1)

model0.save("model0.pkl")
model1.save("model1.pkl")
model2.save("model2.pkl")
```

For making new predictions, my code would look something like this:

```
#Loading Models
model0 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model0.pkl")
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model1.pkl")
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model("model2.pkl")

#Finding Weights (based on train score)

train_nn_predictions = model0.predict(X_train)
train['X'],train['Y'],train['Z'] = train_nn_predictions[:,0],train_nn_predictions[:,1],train_nn_predictions[:,2]     
nn0 = #training score metric (irrelevant to show how it is calculated here)
print("Average Train Score for Model 0 is:",nn0)

train_nn_predictions = model1.predict(X_train)
train['X'],train['Y'],train['Z'] = train_nn_predictions[:,0],train_nn_predictions[:,1],train_nn_predictions[:,2]     
nn1 = #training score metric (irrelevant to show how it is calculated here)
print("Average Train Score for Model 1 is:",nn1)

train_nn_predictions = model2.predict(X_train)
train['X'],train['Y'],train['Z'] = train_nn_predictions[:,0],train_nn_predictions[:,1],train_nn_predictions[:,2]     
nn2 = #training score metric (irrelevant to show how it is calculated here)
print("Average Train Score for Model 2 is:",nn2)

#Apply the weightings for each of the models
w0,w1,w2 = 1/nn0,1/nn1,1/nn2

#New Predictions
new_record = np.array([my variables])
target_predictions = (w0*model0.predict(new_record)+w1*model1.predict(new_record)+w2*model2.predict(new_record))/(w0+w1+w2)
```

Comment: Is there a way of creating a class with a list of models? Yes. Is it an easy one? No. You're better off just writing a couple functions wrapping the load/save operations and keep all pickles in one separate folder.

Comment: Smth simple will do, like `def save_models(model_list, folder): for idx, model in enumerate(model_list): model.save("{}/model{}.pkl".format(folder,idx))` and `def load_models(foldername): return [tf.keras.models.load_model(file) for file in blob.blob(foldername+"/*.pkl")]`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to:

1. Merge all the models using **layers.concatenate**. It will create an output for all the 50 models. For more details regarding the code check: 
   According to https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/:

> x = np.arange(20).reshape(2, 2, 5)
>
> y = np.arange(20, 30).reshape(2, 1, 5)
>
> tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([x, y])

2. Use **KerasPickleWrapper** to pickle it.

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the linked content as a quote in your own answer to prevent them from disappearing due to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)